# How to add Country code(+852) before the phone number in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a CSV file and there is a column (Phone). However, there is no country code before the phone number. What is the syntax I should use in order to add `+852` into every value under the "Phone" column?

Also, how could I remove the space within the phone number for every value under "Phone" column?

For example: Right now, the value is `9123 4567`.
The value that I want afterwards is `+85291234567`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your 'phone' column is in string format you could do the following commands:

a) use replace to remove the spaces (where df is the name of your datraframe)

```
df.phone = df.phone.apply(lambda x: x.replace(" ", ""))
```

b) concatenate the phone column with the country code

```
country_code = "+852"
df.phone = country_code + df.phone
```

In case the phone column is not in string format you will need to convert it.